# Como pegar apenas um elemento de um array associativo

Tags: php, json, array-associativo

Eu estou puxando da API do Cosmos os dados de um produto, ele me retorna um json que eu converti para um array string usando `$array = json_decode($data);`

Quando executo o `var_dump($array)` ele me retorna isso:

```
object(stdClass)#34 (15) {

["description"]=> string(58) "ABSORVENTE COM ABAS INTIMUS GEL C/32 TRI PROTECT SECA UNIT"

["gtin"]=> float(7896007544059)

["thumbnail"]=> string(57) "https://cdn-cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/products/7896007544059"

["price"]=> string(8) "R$ 11,99"
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar apenas o link da ["thumbnail"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente desta maneira:
$array->thumbnail;

Pois como não foi passado o parâmetro true no json_decode, ele está retornando um objeto.

Comment: Cara, valeu, funcionou certinho!